# could not find or load main class sec java

Tags: java, package

file name first.java

```
package p1;

public class first
{
int a;
    public void display()
{
    System.out.println(a);
}

}
```

second file sec.java

```
package p2;

import p1.first;

class sec
{   
public static void main(String args[])
    {   
first obj=new first();  
obj.display();  
}

}
```

getting this error when i try to run after compilation

Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

```
PS C:\Users\shaik\Documents\Java> javac -d C:\Users\shaik\Documents\Java first.java
PS C:\Users\shaik\Documents\Java> javac -d C:\Users\shaik\Documents\Java sec.java
PS C:\Users\shaik\Documents\Java> java -classpath C:\Users\shaik\Documents\Java sec

Error: Could not find or load main class sec
```

Comment: your class is in a package, you don't run your statement in a package

Comment: but yesterday i ran same code and its ran perfectly but today i delete sec.class from folder and compile and run again but getting this error.

Answer (score 0):

file structure must match package structure. You need some directory we'll call 'sourcebase', which contains a dir named `p1`, and in that dir there needs to be a file named `first.java`.

Then to run this code after you compiled it, you need a dir we'll call 'classbase', containing a dir named `p1`, containing a file named `first.class`. Same goes for your sec class. Once you have all that, you can run:

```
java -classpath classbase p2.sec
```

note also that the name of your class is `p2.sec`. Not `sec`. No amount of classpath finagling would even make `java sec` run your app. Within source code, if you're in the same package (so, `p2`), or you have an `import p2.sec;` statemente at the top, you get to just type `sec` to refer to `p2.sec` but everywhere else, including as argument to the `java` application, it is called `p2.sec`.

Comment: actually, the name of the class is sec. p2 is the package it's in

Comment: yesterday i ran same code and its ran perfectly but today i delete sec.class from folder and compile and run again but getting this error.

Comment: got it dude now i understand i run file with package name, but why yesterday it run without package name?

Comment: is it possible that yesterday you executed the java statement from within the package?